# how do i comparison argument in two list

Tags: python, list, arguments, comparison, character

Comparison character in python list
But they must be like

for example `list[0]` and `list[0]` or `list[1]` and `list[1]`

```
n=int(input())
kl=0
k=input()
l=input()
k_l=list(k)
l_l=list(l)
new_list=[]
for element in k_l:
    if element in l_l:
        new_list.append(element)
        for k in new_list:
            if k==k:
                kl=kl+1
print(kl)
```

//ol.input: ABC
aBD
output:2

Comment: why is the output 2 and not 1?  there is only one equal position(B)

Comment: Please remake the question. What is your problem? What your code did you didn't want to happen?

Comment: christian understand what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one line using sum and zip.

```
a = 'ABC'
b = 'ABD'

sum(i == j for i, j in zip(a, b))
```